# Load large data files in python across modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-import

I have multiple python scripts which load same csv/pickle files which are pretty large in size. So I want to load them only once and use them across multiple scripts. If I load them in every script I have then I run out of memory. If I can load them only once and use in multiple scripts that would solve my issue.

Note-1. I do not modify the data files in my scripts. Just read only use in all my scripts.

Note-2. I do not want to merge these scripts into one as its easy to maintain for their respective authors

I tried using a file like config.py which was like this:

```
import pandas as pd

global large_file
large_file= pd.read_csv('large_file.csv')
```

Then imported this in scripts like this:

Script1.py:

```
from config import large_file
print(large_file.shape)
```

Script2.py:

```
from config import large_file
print(large_file.shape)
```

Both scripts load the file which takes lot of time and uses double memory.

Comment: I just do this to run both scripts:

python Sript1.py

and 

python Sript2.py

I put sleep(1000) in first script and then ran second script and it took time to load the file again.

Comment: what IDE do you use ? or are you just using the terminal ?

Comment: Just using terminal. I run them in Linux screen sessions so that they can continue to run in the background.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by creating a separate python module that loads the csv/pickle files and stores them in memory, then import that module in all the scripts that need to use the data.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running your scripts one by one, you can start a single python interpreter and feed it one script after the other using python's [runpy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html) module.

```py
import runpy
_ = runpy.run_module("Script1", run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)
_ = runpy.run_module("Script2", run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)
```

since only a single interpreter is invoked the module is still in the memory and doesn't need to be re-loaded.

this functionality is available in most IDEs like pycharm's `run file in python console` button or spyder `run file` button, or a similar button in VsCode, but they require some settings modifications.

you can run both scripts concurrently with the `threading` module but the result will be really slow due to the global interpreter lock.

---

for larger scale problems where you need concurrent access to the data from multiple processes, you would store the data in a database like [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) or [redis](https://redis.io/) or a python `multiprocessing.Manager` and only read the data that you use from it at runtime instead of reading the entire database.